# How do you crop a video in the current Blender Video Editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

How do you correctly crop a video in blender and remove all resulting blank space that appears along the side of the video?

[image: Crop example]

I have already applied the "Crop" and "Offset" options in the video transform settings, but that results in the blank space shown in the attached image. I found a tutorial that shows you can modify the render dimensions to remove the space (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2MVqRYUatI), but the interface is outdated and if you update the dimensions in the "Output" panel, all it does is scale the video resolution down (not actually changing the dimensions).

Does anyone know how to crop a video and remove blank bar on the side?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the resolution of the project to fit your image, select the image strip, and select this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just took a look and it looks like that menu is specific to images (I'm trying to crop a video).

However, I did find the set render size option for video nested under [Strip > Movie Strip > Set Render Size]. When I tried clicking it, I notice the resolution of the "output" is changed, but it does not seem to remove the blank bar on the side of the video.

Comment: That function should change the output resolution to fit the active strip(white outline + white text). So if you selected that strip above the area to the right in your screenshot above should be removed(remember to uncheck crop and offset from that strip).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I was able to get an effective crop by:

1. Selecting Strip > Movie Strip > Set Render Size
2. Enabling offset -> SET POSITION X TO BE A NEGATIVE NUMBER (this was used to crop the left side of the image)
3. Enabling crop -> SET RIGHT TO BE A POSITIVE NUMBER (this was used to crop the right side of the image)
4. Changing the Output Resolution X by subtracting the sum of the absolute value of offset x + crop right

My issue previously was that I was setting the Crop left and right, which results in distortions when changing the resolution.

Comment: I have previously tried to address the oddities of crop and offset(but later gave up on trying to improve the vse): https://developer.blender.org/T74323

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @tintwotin for pointing me in the right direction, I was able to get an effective crop by:

1. Selecting Strip > Movie Strip > Set Render Size
2. Enabling offset -> SET POSITION X TO BE A NEGATIVE NUMBER (this was used to crop the left side of the image)
3. Enabling crop -> SET RIGHT TO BE A POSITIVE NUMBER (this was used to crop the right side of the image)
4. Changing the Output Resolution X by subtracting the sum of the absolute value of offset x + crop right values

My issue previously was that I was setting the Crop left and right, which results in distortions when changing the resolution.